# Next JS not supported optional chaining

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

Why is optional chaining not supported?

```
/.next/server/chunks/725.js:407
       }, breadcrumb.title ?? idx) : /*#__PURE__*/ react_jsx_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsx("div", {
                            ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

Next 12.0.7,
typescript 4.5.3,
webpack5

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "es2020"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
  },
  ...
}
```

next.config.js

```
module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  return {
    ...defaultConfig,
    future: {
      webpack5: true
    }
  };
};
```

What do I need to do to enable support for optional chaining? Thanks

Comment: Looks like nullish coalescing operator, not optional chaining.

Comment: For optional chaining shouldn't `??` be `?.`  ? Next 9.1.7 or above should support `??` - nullish coalescing.

Comment: What version of Node.js? The versions of Next and Webpack do not matter in this equation. The TypeScript compiler can be configured to generate code for a version of Node that does not understand `??`.

Comment: Thanks @axiac. I updated version node